# Calculate Total male Total Female in powerbi report

Tags: powerbi

I want to count the total number of males and females in a powerbi report

eg.

```
Name    Gender
std1    Female
std2    Male
std3    Female
std4    Male
std5    Male
std6    Male
```

The result I want is:

```
Female 2
Male   4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the results you are looking for, follow these steps:

1. Make a second table using the New Table button with the following code:

   ```
   GenderCounts = DISTINCT(TableName[Gender])
   ```
2. Make a relationship from the newly create table back to the original table
   [image: Relationship on Gender column]
3. Add a new column to the GenderCounts table with the following code:

   ```
   Count = COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(TableName))
   ```

And there you have a second table containing the counts of each gender.
[image: Results]

For more information and other possibilities, check out a related Power BI Community forum post [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-function-to-count-specific-text-values-from-a-column/m-p/78109/highlight/true#M32536) and Stackoverflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029297/count-failures-in-powerbi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350523/when-using-group-by-in-powerbi-desktop-column-value-is-not-active).