# PowerBI DAX function to count number of occurrences using DISTINCT (Countif)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a column in PowerBI that counts how times a customer name occurs in a list.

I may be going in the wrong direction, but what I have so far is;

My SQL query returns a table of customer site visits (*Query1*), from which I have created a new table (*Unique*) and column (*Customer*) that lists the distinct names (*cust_company_descr*) from *Query1*;

> Unique = DISTINCT(Query1[cust_company_descr])

What I need is a new column in the *Unique* table (*Count*) that will give me a count of how many times each customer name in the *Query1* table appears.

If I were working in Excel, the solution would be to generate a list of unique values and do a COUNTIF, but I can't find a way to replicate this.

---

I have seen a few solutions that involve this sort of thing;

> CountValues =
>   CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( TableName ); TableName[ColumnName] = " This Value " )

The issue I have with this is the *Unique* table contains over 300 unique entries, so I can't make this work.

---

Example (The **Count** column is what I'm trying to create)

*Query 1*
**cust_company_descr**
Company A
Company B
Company A
Company C
Company B
Company A

*Unique*
**Company**_____**Count**
Company A_____3
Company B_____2
Company C_____1

Any help is gratefully received.

Comment: Please see my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746142/calculate-total-male-total-female-in-powerbi-report/44766046#44766046).

Comment: Did you create a relationship between the two tables on the Company column? I believe `COUNTA(RELATED(Query1[cust_company_descr])` will do then.

Comment: Yes. The *cust_company_descr* field on the *Query1* table is linked to the *Customer* field on the *Unique* table, by a 'Many-to-One' relationship.    It doesn't appear to work though - I'm gettting the error "The COUNTA function only accept a column reference as an argument."

Comment: You are adding a calculated column, right? Did you also try `COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(TableName))` as @Joe suggested?

Comment: Damn! I didn't see the link in the comment! @Joe 's answer works! Thanks all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate Total male Total Female in powerbi report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746142/calculate-total-male-total-female-in-powerbi-report)

Answer (score 0):

By default a column participating on the one side of a many-to-one relationship will have open context, i.e., no filters are applied to the many side. What we need to do here to "COUNTIF" is to return the subset of `'Query 1'` that references the current row of `'Unique'`. We can accomplish this with [RELATEDTABLE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/relatedtable-function-dax). `RELATEDTABLE()` changes the data filter context to only return target rows referencing the current row.

Note, `RELATED()` goes the opposite direction, filtering from many to one, and returns a single value (unlike `RELATEDTABLE()`, which returns a table).

Once we apply `RELATEDTABLE()`, we only have to count the rows returned  with the `COUNTROWS()` function.

```
COUNTROWS( RELATEDTABLE( 'Query 1' ) )
```

Because `RELATEDTABLE()` leverages the storage engine, this query will be blazingly fast. The biggest factor that could slow down your expression is the number of unique values there are. However, I would not expect a performance decrease until you were into the millions of values.

---

Excellent further reading material at [sqlbi.com](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-related-and-relatedtable-in-dax/) if you are interested.